# gpg2 --refresh-keys general error

Tags: gnupg, tls, keyserver

unfortunately I experience the following error when running

```
$ gpg2 --refresh-keys
gpg: refreshing 18 keys from hkps://keys.openpgp.org
gpg: keyserver refresh failed: General error
```

As you can gather from the above, I've configured the keyserver to be `hkps://keys.openpgp.org` in `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` as suggested [here](https://keys.openpgp.org/about/usage). This is the full content of `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`:

```
keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org
verbose
debug 4096
debug-level 4096
debug-all
log-file /tmp/dirmngr.log
```

Running `gpg2 --refresh-keys` again after `pkill dirmngr` gives this in `/tmp/dirmngr.log`

```
2020-04-19 23:36:35 dirmngr[20588.0] listening on socket '/home/whoami/.gnupg/S.dirmngr'
2020-04-19 23:36:35 dirmngr[20589.0] can't access directory '/etc/gnupg2/trusted-certs': No such file or directory
2020-04-19 23:36:35 dirmngr[20589.0] can't access directory '/etc/gnupg2/extra-certs': No such file or directory
2020-04-19 23:36:35 dirmngr[20589.0] permanently loaded certificates: 0
2020-04-19 23:36:35 dirmngr[20589.0]     runtime cached certificates: 0
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] handler for fd 0 started
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 -> # Home: /home/whoami/.gnupg
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 -> # Config: /home/whoami/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 -> OK Dirmngr 2.1.11 at your service
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] connection from process 20586 (1000:1000)
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 <- GETINFO version
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 -> D 2.1.11
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 -> OK
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 <- KEYSERVER
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 -> S KEYSERVER hkps://keys.openpgp.org
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 -> OK
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: chan_0 <- KS_GET -- LIST_OF_KEYS
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] resolve_dns_addr for 'keys.openpgp.org': 'keys.openpgp.org' [already known]
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] resolve_dns_addr for 'keys.openpgp.org': 'keys.openpgp.org' [already known]
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] TLS verification of peer failed: status=0x0042
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] TLS verification of peer failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. 
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: expected hostname: keys.openpgp.org
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: BEGIN Certificate 'server[0]':
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:      serial: 031419524A880F1D74B7C7BF3514F95D3FFA
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:   notBefore: 2020-04-02 04:32:09
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:    notAfter: 2020-07-01 04:32:09
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:      issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:     subject: CN=keys.openpgp.org
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:   hash algo: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:   SHA1 fingerprint: 447582CA4F0DDA406F88D52DBBDF35B16C060B7D
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: END Certificate
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: BEGIN Certificate 'server[1]':
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:      serial: 0A0141420000015385736A0B85ECA708
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:   notBefore: 2016-03-17 16:40:46
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:    notAfter: 2021-03-17 16:40:46
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:      issuer: CN=DST Root CA X3,O=Digital Signature Trust Co.
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:     subject: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:   hash algo: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG:   SHA1 fingerprint: E6A3B45B062D509B3382282D196EFE97D5956CCB
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] DBG: END Certificate
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] TLS connection authentication failed: General error
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] error connecting to 'https://keys.openpgp.org:443': General error
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] TLS verification of peer failed: status=0x0042
2020-04-19 23:36:36 dirmngr[20589.0] TLS verification of peer failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.
```

What's the problem here?

- Do I have to specify (TLS) certificates for `gpg2` separately? If yes, how do I do so?
- Or am I missing something in `~./gnupg/dirmngr.conf`?
- Or why else is the TLS connection failing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT 1**

```
$ gpg2 --version | head -n 1
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$ dirmngr --version | head -n 1
dirmngr (GnuPG) 2.1.11
```

After reading the log more thoroughly and checking the `dirmngr` manpage, I realized that on my system the whole `/etc/gnupg` directory is missing.

> ```
> FILES
>
>    Dirmngr makes use of several directories when running in daemon mode:
>
>    ~/.gnupg
>
>    /etc/gnupg
>           The first is the standard home directory for  all  configuration
>           files.   In  the deprecated system daemon mode the second direc‐
>           tory is used instead.
>
>    /etc/gnupg/trusted-certs
>           This directory should be filled with certificates  of  Root  CAs
>           you are trusting in checking the CRLs and signing OCSP Reponses.
>
>           Usually  these are the same certificates you use with the appli‐
>           cations making use of dirmngr.  It  is  expected  that  each  of
>           these certificate files contain exactly one DER encoded certifi‐
>           cate in a file with the suffix ‘.crt’ or ‘.der’.  dirmngr  reads
>           those certificates on startup and when given a SIGHUP.  Certifi‐
>           cates which are not readable or do not make up  a  proper  X.509
>           certificate are ignored; see the log file for details.
>
>           Applications  using  dirmngr (e.g. gpgsm) can request these cer‐
>           tificates to complete a trust chain in the same way as with  the
>           extra-certs directory (see below).
>
>           Note that for OCSP responses the certificate specified using the
>           option --ocsp-signer is always considered  valid  to  sign  OCSP
>           requests.
>
>    /etc/gnupg/extra-certs
>           This  directory  may  contain  extra certificates which are pre‐
>           loaded into the interal cache  on  startup.  Applications  using
>           dirmngr (e.g. gpgsm) can request cached certificates to complete
>           a trust chain.  This is convenient in cases you  have  a  couple
>           intermediate  CA  certificates  or certificates ususally used to
>           sign OCSP reponses.  These certificates are first  tried  before
>           going  out to the net to look for them.  These certificates must
>           also be DER encoded and suffixed with ‘.crt’ or ‘.der’.
> ```

Since this might be of relevance, how can I create and fill `/etc/gnupg` with its default values? Or do I have to do it manually? And why is this directory missing in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

> Or am I missing something in ~./gnupg/dirmngr.conf?

For me the following fixed it:

```
$ echo "hkp-cacert /usr/share/gnupg/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf
```

The documentation says that if `hkp-cacert` isn't specified it uses the system certificate store for regular hostnames and the the bundled certificate for the default keyserver pool.

```
$ gpg --search-keys 0B7F8B60E3EDFAE3
gpg: error searching keyserver: General error
gpg: keyserver search failed: General error

$ echo "hkp-cacert /usr/share/gnupg/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf

$ systemctl --user stop dirmngr.service  # or restart manually, this assumes socket activation
$ gpg --search-keys 0B7F8B60E3EDFAE3
gpg: data source: https://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net:443
(1)     Kristian Fiskerstrand <kf@gnupg.net>
        Kristian Fiskerstrand <k_f@gentoo.org>
        Kristian Fiskerstrand <kf@sumptuouscapital.com>
        Kristian Fiskerstrand <kristian.fiskerstrand@sumptuouscapital.com>
          4096 bit RSA key 0B7F8B60E3EDFAE3, created: 2007-12-15, expires: 2020-12-31
...

$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.21
```

Encountered this on 3 machines and it fixed it on 2 machines (Ubuntu Docker and Arch Linux) and the third Arch machine never worked with hkps, only hkp.  Despite having the same version of gnupg, no strange configs in `~/gnupg.conf`, and on the same network.

Seems that just specifying `keyserver pgp.mit.edu` in `gnupg.conf` also fixes it by dropping to the hkp protocol

Pool overview: https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php

Comment: These instructions helped me fix an issue on Arch where `pacman-key --refresh-keys` wasn't working. In that specific case, `echo "hkp-cacert /usr/share/gnupg/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem" | sudo tee /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/dirmngr.conf` fixed the issue. Thanks Kyle!

Comment: @Kyle it is not recommended to use the keyserver pools anymore because of the [certificate spamming problem](https://gist.github.com/rjhansen/67ab921ffb4084c865b3618d6955275f).